How can I properly run a git clone repo?
Problem that appear:

Same here:

I'm currently facing an issue with deploying a Flutter project after cloning it from a Git repository. Despite successfully cloning the repository, I encounter errors when attempting to deploy the program.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to properly run a git clone on a Flutter project? Additionally, if you've encountered similar issues during deployment, I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions you could share.
Thank you in advance for your help!"

please run flutter doctor in your terminal and share the result

Run flutter pub get , when you clone a repo, you did not get the packages and plugins, you need to install them on your own, just like we do npm install when cloning a website repo, in flutter also to get packages you need to run flutter pub get

to Successfully clone a flutter git repo follow these steps
use terminal to get repo
git clone github.com/yourRepo.git 

Then run
flutter pub get 

after that it will download app repos
after that to run application you should use
flutter run 

ps. if it still doesn't works, run command
flutter doctor 

and share screenshot
